# Ruby: is there a way I can do an assignment like this: self.value_at_location(x,y)=value?

Tags: ruby

I know I could do

```
self.value_at_location=(x,y,value)
```

by defining the method as `value_at_location=(x,y,value)`

but for readability, I think it would be AWESOME if `value_at_location(x,y)=(value)` was possible. or something like it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, if you define `def x=( y, z )` you can never call it as `foo.x = 17, 42` (you'll get "1 argument for 2" error), but you can do: `foo.send(:x=, 17, 42)`. With this, though, you might as well do what @sepp2k suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't define a setter method to do `foo(x,y) = value`.

But what you can do is define `[]=(x,y,value)`, so that you can call `self[x,y] = value`.

Answer (score 1):

One could, hypothetically, do some weird stuff with metaprograming:

```
class Point
     ...
     def location_at_value(x, y)
          x = Object.new
          x.define_method(:=) { |value| @value[x, y] = value }
          return x
     end
end
```

<del>Note that I haven't tested this, but it should work, in theory.</del> This doesn't work, see comment below.

Comment: No one could not because a) `=` is not a valid method name and b) you can't redefine assignment, so even if you could define a method named `=`, it'd only be callable using `send`, which doesn't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to do this:

```
class Point
  attr_reader :x, :y, :value
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize
    @value = [@x,@y]
  end

  def value_at x y
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

end
```